# Generate HTML with Jade based on Input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Basically im trying to give the user the possibility to generate a list with a specific number of list entries. If he enters the number "50", i want to automatically generate a list with 50 list entries.

I'm using Jade and Bootstrap right now.

My code looks like this, but apparently is not working. Is there a simple way/change to achieve my goal or am i completely on the wrong track?
The first occuring error occurs by pressing the "Generate Button" because it cannot find the function "generate".

```
h1 1D Lists

    form(role="form")
        div.form-group
            label(for="itemsNumber") How many List Items?
            input(type="number", class="form-control", placeholder="Number of List Items", id="itemsNumber")
        div.form-group
            label(for="alignment") Alignment?
            select.form-control
                option Horizontal
                option Vertical
        button.generate(type="submit", class="btn btn-default", onclick="generate()") Generate


    - var generate = function() {
    - alert("generated!")
    -   var itemsNumber = document.getElementById("itemsNumber").value;
    -   $("list").html("+list(itemsNumber)");
    - }

    mixin list(number)
        div.list        
            ul.list-group.level1
                a.list-group-item.listhead
                    i.fa.fa-list  My List
                - for (var i = 0; i < number; ++i){
                    a(href="#").list-group-item Entry #{i}

                - }
```

Answer (score 0):

your generate function is only available at **jade compile time**,
not at **javascript execution time** (in the browser)

so put your function into a `<script>` tag, in jade with `script.`